# Is there a $3$-commutative algebra?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, noncommutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. If $m\ge2$, I denote $P_m$ the *standard polynomial* in $m$ non-commutating indeterminates:
$$P_m(X_1,\dotsc,X_m)=\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak S_m}\epsilon(\sigma)X_{\sigma(1)}\dotsm X_{\sigma(m)}.$$
We say that a $k$-algebra $A$ is $m$-commutative if $P_m$ is an identity over $A$, that is
$$\forall a_1,\dotsc,a_m\in A,\qquad P_m(a_1,\dotsc,a_m)=0,$$
and $P_{m-1}$ is not. Remark that $2$-commutativity is just commutativity.

Amitsur–Levitzki's Theorem is that $M_n(k)$ is $(2n)$-commutative.

> My question is whether there exist (interesting) algebras that are $m$-commutative for an odd $m$. For instance, what would be an example of a $3$-commutative algebra ?

**Edit**. As [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430620/is-there-a-3-commutative-algebra#comment1108101_430620) by *user49822*, $A$ may not be unital, otherwise $(2k+1)$-commutativity implies $(2k)$-commutativity by specifying $a_m=1$. Thus there remains the question of whether a non-unital algebra can be $3$-commutative.

Salvatore's answer gives an explicit, practical example of a $3$-commutative algebra. However it is a bit too narrow to my taste, because its ideal of polynomial identities contains (presumably : is generated by) the monomial $X_1X_2X_3$. This leads me to strengthen my question:

> What is an algebra $A$ whose ideal of polynomial identities is $(P_3)$ ?

Comment: Assuming $A$ is unital, if $m=2k+1$ and you substitute $X_m=1$ then the identity becomes the identity of $m-1$-commutativity

Comment: @user49822 Oh yes ! Thank you for the remark.

Comment: @LSpice I am not sure to understand. $M_n(k)$ is $(2n)$-commutative in the sense I gave : there exist $2n-1$ matrices $a_j$ such that $P_{2n-1}(a_1,\ldots,a_{2n-1})\ne0$.

Comment: @DenisSerre, I am sorry, I misunderstood @‍user49822's [remark](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430620/is-there-a-3-commutative-algebra#comment1108101_430620).  I have deleted my comment.

Comment: I believe the terminology is misleading and the failure of commutativity should not be assumed (so that 3-commutative defines a variety). So the real question is about non-commutative 3-commutative algebras.

Comment: I guess that these algebras are implicitly assumed associative, else a product of 3 or more algebras is not well-defined; is that what you meant?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Yes, I assume associative algebra.

Answer (score 12):

An easy example of 3-commutative algebra is $T_3(F)$, the algebra of all strictly upper triangular 3-by-3 matrices.

Another class of examples is given by the quandle rings $F[X]$, where $F$ is a field and $X$ a trivial quandle with more than one element.

Comment: I see. This is so because every $3$-terms product $PQR$ vanishes. Somehow a trivial case, though perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Sure, Denis. I just added another class of examples in my answer.

Comment: If I remember the definition of the trivial quandle correctly, the quandle ring of a trivial quandle satisfies the stronger identity $(xy-yx)z=0$, right?

Comment: Exactly, this is just the case, as $xy=y$ for all $x,y\in X$.

Comment: @SalvatoreSiciliano thanks! This remark clarifies some things I heard about quandles (in the context of knots, so nontrivial quandles) before...

Answer (score 9):

This answer may be a bit anticlimactic, but you can take free associative algebra without $1$ (same as ideal of positive degree elements in tensor algebra) and look at its quotient by *all* products of degree 3 (or any other $n$). It's easy to see that obtained algebra will be strictly $n$-commutative in your sense (it's almost obvious: tensor algebra is strictly graded). Study of properties and representations of such *nil-rings* was quite popular few decades ago, but now mostly fell into obscurity.

Similarly you can take an ideal generated in free nonunital algebra by all substitutions of its elements into $n$-commutativity relation; quotient of tensor algebra by constructed ideal will be a free algebra in a variety defined by that relation. That varieties do not coincide, as witnessed by example above, so their free algebras would not be isomorphic as well.

Answer (score 5):

This variety of algebras is well studied. In particular, the description of the underlying vector space of the free algebra in this variety follows immediately from

["A note on the T-ideal generated by $s_3(x_1,x_2,x_3)$" by G. D. James,
Israel Journal of Mathematics, 29 (1978), 105–112](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02760404).

The main result of that paper, when translated to free algebras, says that the degree $d$ component of the free algebra generated by $V$ is the following Schur functor of $V$:

$S^{2}(V)\oplus S^{1,1}(V)$ for $d=2$

$S^{4}(V)\oplus 2S^{3,1}(V)\oplus S^{2,2}(V)$ for $d=4$

$S^{d}(V)\oplus 2S^{d-1,1}(V)$ for $d=3$ or $d\ge 5$.

This description, in my opinion, is sufficiently pleasant to have good intuition of what these algebras are, present them by generators and relations, write down convenient bases etc.

Comment: This is a good version of my answer! I wonder if those varieties have some (more or less) explicit relation to $E_n$ algebras.

Comment: @DenisT why would there be a relation? $E_n$ relaxes commutativity in a homotopical context, this relaxes commutativity in a strict context...

Answer (score 5):

I have just thought of another interesting example, which is a bit peculiar, in that the 3-commutativity property arises for a natural *subspace* of an algebra which itself does not satisfy any identity. Specifically, consider the algebra $D_1$ of polynomial differential operators on the line; it consists of linear combinations of elements $x^i\partial^j$, where $\partial x - x\partial =1$ holds. It is well known that this algebra does not satisfy any polynomial identity. However, let us consider the subspace (in fact, a Lie subalgebra) $W_1$ of this algebra consisting of all vector fields; it consists of linear combinations of elements $x^i\partial$. I claim that any three elements of this subspace 3-commute (in some papers, this is described by saying that 3-commutativity is a weak identity of $D_1$ with respect to its Lie subalgebra $W_1$). This follows from the fact that
$$
f\partial g\partial h\partial=f\partial g (h\partial + h')\partial=
f(gh\partial + g'h+gh')\partial^2+f(gh'\partial+gh''+g'h')\partial,
 $$
which can be written as
$$
fgh\partial^3+(fg'h+2fgh')\partial^2+(fgh''+fg'h')\partial,
 $$
and this is clearly killed by total anti-symmetrization in $f,g,h$, and does not follow from any stronger identity.

Comment: I agree the calculation, but this subspace $W_1$ is not by itself an algebra (as you noticed, only a Lie algebra). Thus it does not answer my question.

Comment: @DenisSerre - yes, indeed, I completely agree. Still, it is perhaps useful to have this perspective also, since studying weak identities of various kinds has been at heart of several important breakthroughs in the PI theory in the past. In particular, this observation about $W_1$ came about in a current research project, and I find this instance of 3-commutativity one of the most natural I have seen so far :)

Answer (score 4):

Let $a,b,c$ be basis vectors over some commutative associative algebra $X$. Consider the algebra $A$ spanned by these basis vectors over $X$, with the multiplication rules $pq=q$ for all $p,q \in \{a,b,c\}$, and extend to all of $A$ by requiring that the multiplication is bilinear over $X$. Thus $(ua+vb+wc)(xa+yb+zc)=(u+v+w)(xa+yb+zc)$.

Write $S(xa+yb+zc)=x+y+z \in X$ for convenience, so that one can write $xy=S(x)y$ for all $x,y \in A$.

This gives an associative multiplication, since $(xy)z=S(x)yz=x(yz)$. Now since $ab - ba = b-a$ the algebra isn't commutative. But if I write $xyz+yzx+zxy-yxz-zyx-xzy$ we have $xyz=S(x)S(y)z=yxz$. Thus $P_3(x,y,z)=0$ for all $x,y,z \in A$.

Comment: Is this (the opposite of) @SalvatoreSiciliano's [quandle rings](https://mathoverflow.net/a/430656)?  I think just a 2D $A$ would do.

Comment: Yes 2D would also work.